# mod_pagespeed - internal cache purge issue

Tags: pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

I use mod_pagespeed on my Nginx-Webserver.

When I try to test some of my pages with Google Pagespeed Insights(https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) there are:

1) **Many errors shown the first time I do this**, when the page is not opened manually with a browser before.

2) At the second scan - or if I open my page manually with a browser before - Google Pagespeed Insights **shows me 90+% instantly**.

Some of my sites do not have very large traffic, cause they are niche specific. I do this speed-optimation mostly for ranking purpuses. Now I am worried that Google doesn't see the 90+% when they test my site, because the first scan shows 70-80% and many errors...

Ok... so I think mod_pagespeed purges its internal cache after a while and when the first one opens the site there are no optimized files and because optimation takes to much time, the first user gets some files without full optimation. Right?

**My approach nr.1:**

I have done some optimation so keep the cache for 12h, but my tests show me that it doesn't work. Are here any mistakes in my attempt?

```
 #experimental mweber 400mb 12h
 pagespeed FileCacheSizeKb            409600;
 pagespeed FileCacheCleanIntervalMs   43200000;
 pagespeed FileCacheInodeLimit        500000;
```

**My approach nr.2:**

My hoster give me the advice to warm up the cache with a wget-script, which opens my pages from time to time. I tried that but it doesn't show any effect, so are there any requirements or parameters I have to use with wget, so mod_pagespeeed starts optimation of files?

Would be great to get some tipps and advices from you! ty :)

Answer (score 0):

wget will not trigger any caching, if caching was only triggered via request then wget would not access the files to trigger them anyway as it does not process html to trigger requests on the assets.

Why are you clearing the cache so soon?